# Is there a faster way to enter count data to a data frame in R?

Tags: r

[image]

For example, how do I enter these data to a data frame so that I can construct a logistic regression model.

Otherwise, I will type like this

`Center<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1......,1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Center<-c(rep(1,73),rep(2,52),rep(3,38),rep(4,33),rep(5,29),rep(6,21),rep(7,14),rep(8,13))`

Thanks Ronak

Comment: I don't know how you get 73, 52 etc numbers but you can also do `rep(1:8, c(73, 52, 38, 33, 29,21, 14, 13))`

Comment: Oh,that's the count of cases for each center.  yeah, 1:8 is better. Thank you